# Setting value dynamically using jQuery..

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a value I've inserted into a input field and add/place it dynamically into the value section of a hidden input field using jQuery. I'm using a combination of the .val() and .change() methods which is kind of working but not fully.

Here is my simple HTML

```
<input id="service_amount" name="service_amount" type="text" value="" placeholder="Amount (example 29.00)"/>

<input id="pay_amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="29.00"/>
```

And here is my JS

```
$(function(){
"use strict";

    var myVal1 = $('#service_amount').val();

        $(this).on('change', function(){
            $('#pay_amount').val(myVal1);
        });
});
```

So when I enter a value into the #service_amount field, I need that value to be set as the value for the #pay_amount hidden field. I know a value has already been set for the hidden field, but as you know this gets removed once a new value is set.

Much appreciated in advanced for you help and advice.

Comment: What do you want the `$(this)` variable to represent? I assume you would want to listen to a `change` event on the `$('#service_amount')` element...no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are listening for the `change` event on the wrong element.

The `change` event is occuring on the non hidden element - `$('#service_amount')`, so your change handler should be on that element.

```
$(function(){
"use strict";

    var serviceElem = $('#service_amount'); // caching the selector

    // listen for change event on `$('#service_amount')`
    serviceElem.on('change', function(){
        // Extract the value within the change handler so you get
        // the updated value.
        // We can now use the `$(this)` variable since it points
        // to the correct `$('#service_amount')` element within
        // the event handler.
        var myVal1 = $(this).val(); // could also be `serviceElem.val()`
        $('#pay_amount').val(myVal1);
    });
});
```

Comment: ...thank you Lix, that's work just as i needed it to. Brilliant stuff. Just getting my head around jQuery more...so I will take what you've given and add to the knowledge vault :-). Thank you once again!!!

Comment: @ambtlv - May your vault never run out of space :) Glad to help!